# ASP.NET Membership and EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-membership

I have a table called `Websites` that could have many users. (Many-2-Many relationship between Websites and Users). However, I am using ASP.NET Built-in Membership API and Entity Framework to handle data.

What I would like to do, is to add a User to a Website object using EF as such: website.Users.Add(MembershipUser object here).
Simple as that, if this wasn't the Membership API it would've been much easier. But When creating a new user i'd like to assign access to specific websites from the websites table from a checkbox list.

How can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: I question your logic on this.  Typically, users sign up for only a single website.  Allowing a user to have membership to multiple sites would be confusing for users, and they wouldn't understand why they're already registered for a site they didn't sign up for.

Comment: No actually this is a CMS, and the users do not sign up. The admin gives access to edit one or many websites. Of course the CMS will handle multiple websites that have the same data structure for the same company.

Comment: if the users don't sign up, how do they get a username and password?  I hope you don't email them to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a lot more complex, and you might not be able to get all answers in a single question. I'll try my best.

Here is my approach -

1) Use new [ASP.Net Universal Provider](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingSystemWebProvidersASPNETUniversalProvidersForSessionMembershipRolesAndUserProfileOnSQLCompactAndSQLAzure.aspx)

2) Implement [Custom Membership Provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479048.aspx) and override

```
public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
```

So that you can validate user against **Users** table as well as **Websites** table.

3) Create registration yourself instead of using CreateUserWizard. For example, using regular textboxes.

```
MembershipCreateStatus status;

MembershipUser membershipUser = System.Web.Security.Membership.CreateUser(
UsernameTextBox.Text, PasswordTextBox.Text, EmailTextBox.Text, 
PasswordQuestioTextBox.Text, PasswordAnswerTextBox.Text, true, out status);

// Then assign user to website based on the selected checkboxes
```

**Database Relationship**

[image]

Comment: The solution above also works, how is yours really better and why? Please let me know.

Comment: If I have to implement like your project, I'll use above steps. If you have any specific question about each step, please ask a new question so that it'll be helpful to others too.

Comment: what I need to know is if the answer above you is bad in practice because it may result in future errors just for creating a relationship with the membership api tables.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply; I was on vacation. It is ok to create relationships with Membership Tables (as long as you won't add/delete columns to it). I added the screenshot; I hope it'll help you keep going.

Comment: Exactly how I did it. Thank you both :)

Answer (score 1):

You can include the `aspnet_Users` table in your mapping and add the respective constraints in the websites' table. EF will then provide a class representing the users and a collection of these as a navigation property on `Websites`.

Comment: Dennis, thank you for the answer. I'm not sure how to exactly implement this. Should I have a foreign key in the Websites table? I need a many-2-many relationship here.

Comment: You will probably need an association table then. `Users_on_Websites` for instance. This table will have the `UserId` and a `WebsiteId` as its only columns. They must be linked to `aspnet_Users` and `websites` as foreign keys. If you include the three tables in your EF Mapping, then EF will recognize the m-to-n relationship.

Comment: @user1027620 - many to many relationships require a separate table to manage the joins.  This is sometimes call a junction table, a joint table, a link table, etc..

Comment: When calling `website.Users.Add(`How can I add a MembershipUser here`)` ? I know about junction tables but I didn't think that doing the above with the ASP membership was good.

Comment: Please consider doing some research on the topic. Here's an introduction by the well-known author Julie Lerman (in VB.Net, but quite comprehensible anyway): http://learnentityframework.com/LearnEntityFramework/tutorials/many-to-many-relationships-in-the-entity-data-model